# How to split a word in list of two characters

Tags: python, regex, transition

I have a Word: HAPPY
I want to split the word HAPPY like this {"HA", "AP", "PP", "PY"} using python.

I tried the function:

```
itertools.combinations("HAPPY", 2)
```

This finds me all the possible combinations from the word HAPPY, which I don't want. All I want is to find all the transitions between the characters.

I would appraciate any suggestions. Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a regex:

```
import re

s = 'HAPPY'
print(re.findall(r'(?=(..))', s))
// => ['HA', 'AP', 'PP', 'PY']
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/xDAXw7)

The [`(?=(..))`](https://regex101.com/r/wjOSsn/1) pattern finds a location followed with any 2 chars other than line break chars and captures these 2 chars. Then, the regex engine steps forward to the next location and grabs two more chars, and so on.

As for performance, if you compile the regex the performance difference is not that big, but comprehension should be a bit faster:

```
import re
import time

s = 'HAPPY'
rx = re.compile(r'(?=(..))', re.DOTALL)

def test_regex():
    return rx.findall(s)

def test_comprehension():
    return [(s)[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(s)-1)]

n = 10000
t0 = time.time()
for i in range(n): test_regex()
t1 = time.time()
print('regex: {}'.format(t1-t0))

t0 = time.time()
for i in range(n): test_comprehension()
t1 = time.time()
print('comprehension: {}'.format(t1-t0))
# => regex: 0.00773191452026
# => comprehension: 0.00626182556152
```

See the [online test](http://ideone.com/4hduku)

Comment: The OP suggest they want a `set` output (although I don't actually believe them)

Comment: For what it's worth, if I came across this in source code, I would have no idea what it was doing. The list comprehension answers are, IMO, much more understandable.

Comment: Thank you for the fast Answer. I clearly agree that list comprehension is more understandable. But my question would be, which one is the better solution regarding the performance issue?

Comment: @Proma: Comprehension should be faster.

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty list comprehension

```
[("HAPPY")[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len("HAPPY")-1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
word = 'HAPPY'
combos = [word[i:i+2] for i in range(len(word) - 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension to take all the two character slices in the string.

```
string = "HAPPY"
[string[idx:idx+2] for idx in range(len(string))]
```